# Magento 2 Frontend Toggle Button - Show Hide Content - Options

Tags: javascript, toggle

How can I achieve on Magento 2 Frontend show a toggle button which will show/hide a custom option text area for user to fill in?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the PHTML file where you want to add these toggle option.

then add the tag script to add some jQuery functionality.

```
 <script>
require([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
     //Your code to show/hide the form users want to fill
     })</script>
```

To customize the style of the toggle button you can use CSS or add some bootstrap styles.